# Function based Indexes and user_tab_cols

Tags: oracle, plsql

Why an entry is created in user_tab_cols when we create a function based on a column of a table?

```
 create table t1(a varchar2(100), b number);

 select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'T1'; -- Two rows coming

 create index idx1 on t1(upper(a));

 select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'T1'; -- Three rows coming
```

What is the reason to put an entry in user_tab_cols?

Comment: Did you bother to have a look at the data returned by user_tab_cols? You might have gotten a clue that would have answered your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra column is a [virtual column](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php) that Oracle has added to store the value of the indexed expression.  From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS254):

> Oracle Database represents the index expression as a virtual column

You can easily verify in SQL*Plus that the extra column is virtual.  In fact, it is also a 'hidden' column:

```
SQL> select column_name, hidden_column, virtual_column from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'T1';

COLUMN_NAME                    HID VIR
------------------------------ --- ---
A                              NO  NO
B                              NO  NO
SYS_NC00003$                   YES YES
```

The name of the virtual column may be different on your machine.

`user_tab_columns` filters out hidden columns, as explained in the [Oracle documentation for `user_tab_cols`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5428.htm#REFRN26276).  So, if you don't wish to see this column, you can query `user_tab_columns` instead of `user_tab_cols`:

```
SQL> select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'T1';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
A
B

SQL>
```